Books with trading/investing case studies
I'm interested in books (or similar resources) with detailed case studies in trading or investing. I.e. cases in the past where someone found an opportunity, executed a strategy, and saw the results. Ideally some cases where the strategy lost money too.
So far I've identified "Inside the Investments of Warren Buffett" by Lu and "The Alchemy of Finance" by Soros. There were also some cases from Jane Street in the book "Going Infinite" by Lewis.

To round out your studies with an alternative viewpoint, see Larry Swedroe's Wise Investing Made Simple.

Another good one is "The Intelligent Investor" by Ben Graham (see for example https://www.amazon.com/Intelligent-Investor-Definitive-Investing-Essentials/dp/0060555661) The guy was Warren Buffet's teacher and has been dead for almost 50 years. Still, even today his conclusions and advice seem perfectly on target (and hence are being ignored by most investors).

If you want answers on this site, you'll probably need to ask an actual question.
